# How can two users join a video call using tokbox?

Tags: android, tokbox

I have already read the document for tokbox video call api.
But still I am having confusion in one scenario i.e., If session id created from server side will be unique everytime and to connect 2 users in a session they should have same session id then how 2 users will connect to each other?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you will need to persist the session id you create in a database (or some other storage) and return it to all of the users in that session. When a user connects to a session on the client application you need three things:

1. TokBox Project API Key (8 digit number found on TokBox project dashboard)
2. TokBox Session ID (created by the server SDK create session method)
3. TokBox Token (this is unique for each user in each different session)

The simple answer is store the Session ID on the server side and when each user is joining the session return the Session ID with the other details they require. There may be other options like broadcasting each users connection details to them after you generate the Session ID but there would be a lot of other considerations to work through before pursuing that option.

Comment: We already thought of this thing and we will br implementing this thing only but the question still remains same how to achieve it. If you have any idea or if you have done it before then share your code or something so that we can try it.